# AbiEncoderV2 encoding Tuple algorithm

Tags: abi, abiencoderv2

Where can I find AbiEncoderV2 encoding Tuple algorithm?

I would like to add Tuples support to a ruby library.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, a tuple is encoded as if all its members were separate parameters, so the following function returns `true`:

```solidity
struct Foo {
  uint x;
  uint y;
  uint z;
}

function foo () public pure returns (bool) {
  return keccak256 (abi.encode (1, 2, 3)) ==
         keccak256 (abi.encode (Foo (1,  2, 3)));
}
```

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, then this dude is looking for a client-side (off-chain) implementation in Ruby.

Comment: No, he is going to implement this in Ruby and wants to understand how it works in Solidity.